# how do i display a default in a loop and hide the rest without creating a infinate loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

im trying to find a way that i can make a default to display in the loop while the rest are hidden and will display on call the one i have now is an infinite loop im looking for either a fix or alternative to my problem

```
for ($i=0 ; $i < $n_products; $i++) {

        $PID = mysql_result($n_products,$i,'PID');
        $prod_thumb = mysql_result($n_products,$i,'thumbnail');
        $prod_des =  mysql_result($n_products,$i, 'description');
        $prod_price =  mysql_result($n_products,$i, 'price');
        $prod_name =  mysql_result($n_products,$i, 'name');
        $prod_img = mysql_result($n_products,$i,'img');
        if ($i = 0){
            echo"<div class=\"ortho_des\">
                    <div style=\"width:275px; height:215px; float:left;\">
                        <img width=\"275px\" height=\"215px\" src=\"$prod_img\"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div style=\"float:left;\">Name: $prod_name</div><br/>
                        <div style=\"float:left;\">Color: $prod_name</div><br/>
                        <div style=\"float:left;\">Price: $prod_price $</div><br/>  
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"clearFloat\">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div>Description: $prod_des</div>

                </div>";

        }else{
            echo"<div class=\"ortho_des\" style=\"display:none;\">
                    <div style=\"width:275px; height:215px; float:left;\">
                        <img width=\"275px\" height=\"215px\" src=\"$prod_img\"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div style=\"float:left;\">Name: $prod_name</div><br/>
                        <div style=\"float:left;\">Color: $prod_name</div><br/>
                        <div style=\"float:left;\">Price: $prod_price $</div><br/>  
                    </div>
                    <div class=\"clearFloat\">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div>Description: $prod_des</div>

                </div>";
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if ($i = 0){` be `if ($i == 0){` ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

You've got a slight syntax error that's throwing you off

```
if ($i = 0){
```

Should be

```
if ($i === 0){
```

Single equals is the assignment operator.  Thus, `$i` is being assigned to `0` every loop, which is why it's going infinitely, instead of to `$n_products`.